# return PartialView to a popup windows at another view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Index.aspx with a button inside which that button will call a controller, doing some logic and returning to a PartialView control - let's named it PopUpPartialView.ascx **(as a popup).** So to make it clear, the popup windows(PopUpPartialView) actually stays ON the top of Index.aspx when user clicks on the button.

In PopUpPartialView.ascx, there is another button, that returns say a GenerateList and now the problem is - how do I pass the thing back to the same popup windows in PopUpPartialView.ascx on the top of Index.aspx as it was before? How should my controller codes look like?

Here's what I have on the return:

return PartialView("PopUpPartialView", GenerateList);

this clearly NOT working as what I want, because it doesn't point back to Index page. I was thinking perhaps to use ajax so that I could stay on that popup ascx page. Confused~~ Someone please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use a plugin which handles all the popup plumbing for you.

My poison of choice is **[jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)**.

It's very easy to work with - essentially a hidden container on the page, and you can load contents in there either on the initial render, or on a click event via AJAX.

So in your example, you could handle the button event click, show the dialog and load the contents of your partial view into the hidden container.